# How to cancel all commits on rollback/readonly in properties, regardless of hibernate, or accessing the database without it

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc

There are many different methods in my application that handle both with and without Hibernate. But for testing the database, I need to "turn off" all commits, so as not to mess up the database. Is there any way to do it, using some kind of bean property? (maybe something like readonly flag or rollback only for any transaction?

Comment: use `@Transactional` annotation, read more here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html

Comment: @mr1554 some methods already contain this annotation, and some do not, unfortunately this part of the code cannot be edited. I can't figure out the documentation, please tell me if it is possible to configure some kind of bean so that absolutely all transactions in the application are, for example, "only rollback"

Comment: please share the code, it will help to get to the right point much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to temporarily revoke the write permissions of the database user you use for accessing the database.